# Comment la locution « de par » est-elle apparue ?

Tags: étymologie, prépositions, locutions

Au départ, lorsque je suis tombé sur *de par*, j'ai pensé que la juxtaposition de deux prépositions dans *de par* était erronée. Or cette locution prépositionnelle  existe. Cf. [Littre](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/de%20par) et le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/par/2).

Quelle est l'étymologie de cette construction ? D'où provient son sens actuel ?

Comment: J'ai reformulé en incluant l'aspect étymologique, j'espère que ça te convient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'entrée du petit Robert :

> DE PAR (Altération de *part*) : De la part de, au nom de ...
>
> > *De par* le roi.
> > *De par* la Loi.

Et voici le sens qu'il propose pour *part* référencé dans *de par* :

> *PART*: 842 *de suo part* "de son côté" latin *pars partis* : Ce qui revient à quelqu'un
>
> > Avoir la meilleure *part*.
> >     La *part* du pauvre.

---

... cela devient alors

- *De par le roi* :  du fait de la *part* du pouvoir qu'il détient, ce qui permet à sa volonté d'agir (de par → par la volonté).
- *De par le monde* : Quelque *part* dans le monde, dans une (ou plusieurs) *part[ie]* du monde (Cf. le lien vers le TLF cité dans la question, dont est extrait cette définition et celle ci-après).
- *De par sa conformation il peut… Du fait de, à cause de…* J'essayerais ici de réintroduire la notion de *part* :

  - Du fait de, à cause de sa conformation *part[iculière]*…
  - Du fait de, à cause de sa *part* de conformation qui lui donne pouvoir de ...

---

C'est l'histoire, l’étymologie et l'évolution due aux usages qui éclairent le sens caché.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Le *dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld Alain Rey) donne bien aussi l'origine de « de par » dans une forme altérée de « de la part de ».

Comment: Je veux bien le croire, mais là il y a un problème de rédaction, je suis incapable de distinguer ce qui est écrit verbatim dans ces références de l'interprétation qu'en fait cl-r.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez j'ai ajouté un trait à la fin des références du petit Robert, Vous pouvez supprimer les références au TLF (références ajoutées pour signifier qu’elles n’ont pas été reprises du petit Robert) si cela obscurcit la lecture, un lecteur attentif ayant suivi le lien TLF de la question comprendra l'origine de ces définitions.

Comment: Je vous suis connaissant et ai plussoyé.